# Magento 2: What are `resources.xml` Files Used For?

Tags: magento2, database, migration, setup

In Magento 2, one of the XML configuration files a module may have is `resources.xml` file.  For example, the sales module has one

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/resources.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/resources.xsd">
    <resource name="sales_setup" extends="core_setup" />
    <resource name="sales" extends="core" />
</config>
```

Does anyone know what these files are used for in Magento 2?  They appear to be the old Magento 1 top level `<resources/>` node.  However, since Magento no longer uses Setup Resource Model/Migrations (instead Magento 2 uses classes in `Setup/InstallSchema.php`, `Setup/InstallData.php`, `Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`, `Setup/UpgradeData.php` for install/migration-like scripts), its not 100% clear what the `sales_setup` resource is for.

For the non setup resource, is this just another way to add a database connection class with different credentials/connection string information? Or something else?

Comment: alan,Can please look at this file `vendor\magento\framework\App\etc\resources.xsd"(4,41)`. may can be give any idea

Comment: @AmitBera That tells how the data in resources.xml should appear, it doesn't tell us what the system uses these files for.

Comment: Sorry,  i did  not have any clear idea about this .If i get any point then i will post

Answer (score 10):

I think the resources is relating to the actual database connection. M1 in the past had something like this:

```
   <resources>
        <backup_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mage_Backup</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </backup_setup>
        <backup_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </backup_write>
        <backup_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </backup_read>
    </resources>
```

so I would say the resources file is the successor to what the connection was.

Not sure that the _setup node provides much value above the other line as we have this code in

lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Config.php

```
public function getConnectionName($resourceName)
{
    $connectionName = \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION;

    $resourceName = preg_replace("/_setup$/", '', $resourceName);
```

and also in setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Setup/ResourceConfig.php

```
class ResourceConfig implements \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConfigInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConnectionName($resourceName)
    {
        return \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION;
    }
}
```

I had a quick look through some of the enterprise modules to see if that sheds more light on the use of the `resources.xml` file (as multiple dbs is apparently an M2 Enterprise feature) but the only use that I have come across so far also only uses extends from `core`.

My hunch is that one would need to create additional db connections in `app/etc/env.php` which then allows you to use those values to override the ones shipped in the default `resource.xml` files (ie just the 1 default connection).

Comment: Just to summarize: 'resources.xml' allows extension developer to specify resource inheritance information and connection linking information.